# Ruby on Rails concurrent database requests crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

My Rails 4 app has a process that runs every hour, which creates/updates 100,000+ records in the database from data in a .csv file.

While this process is running, end users of the app are also attempting to access pages that are database intensive (selecting thousands of records). This is causing the app to time out/crash. These pages load quick when the process mentioned above is not running.

I have tried to use "EM.defer" and "Thread.new", but I think it's my database which is becoming overloaded (CPU and memory are fine). Same issue is happening using thin --threaded and with Passenger.

Here's the code that's loading data into ActiveRecord:

```
  def load_records # load thousands of records from CSV files
    EM.defer do
      loadRecordsFromCSV
    end
  end

  def loadRecordsFromCSV
    require "csv"
    csvfile =  "./lib/csvfile.csv" # 100,000+ lines
    CSV.foreach(csvfile) do |row|
      d = row[0]
      s = row[1]
      g = row[2]
      ss = row[3]
      n = row[4]
      c = row[5]
      cc = row[6]
      p = row[7]
      ad = row[8]
      av = row[9]
      params = { d: d, s: s, g: g, ss: ss, n: n, c: c, cn: cn, p: p, ad: ad, av: av }
      existingFoo = Foo.find_by(d: d, s: s, c: c)
      if existingFoo != nil
        existingFoo.update(params)
      else
        Foo.create(params)
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to set this up that won't freeze/slow my app while it's running? The process takes a couple minutes, and freezing the app for this long each hour is not an option.

I have tried using raw SQL instead of ActiveRecord, and also writing to a temporary table first, but the same problem is occurring.

This is admittedly my first RoR project so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's in the log file; processing 100,000 records shouldn't take a couple of minutes so there is something else going on.

Comment: The log file looks like this (x many lines, sorry if this looks like a mess):                                                    [1m[35mFoo Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "foo".* FROM "foos"  WHERE "foos"."d" = 'd' AND "foos"."s" = 'ABC123' AND "foos"."c" = 'WTF' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  UPDATE "foos" SET "ab" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foos"."id" = 8  [["ab", "---\nMyTextHere: '12345'\n"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-03 16:01:59.718917"]]
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m

Comment: Basically all I see in the log file is the SELECT and UPDATE that would correspond with the .find_by and .update in my code. The whole app is slowing down while this process is running though, and it takes a good 30 seconds to get through just ~5000 records.

Comment: hmm... so I don't do EventMachine - I would look at taking out parts of your code, specifically just (1) call loadRecordsFromCSV via rails console and (2) take out the find by and just create each record (and add at the end of create!). If you want to maintain data in your dev database, just do it in test or something.

Comment: OK, I followed your suggestion and the database is still locking up during multiple .create! actions. However, my other function using raw SQL seems to be working (contrary to what I claimed in the original post). I am starting to wonder if this is an issue with ActiveRecord + SQLite...

Comment: which db are you going to use in prod? I tend to only use SQLite for hashing out a concept but maintain same db from prod to localhost for these reasons (I use postgres). I could see there being a concurrency problem with SQLite but just not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. I rewrote my record loading functions using raw SQL instead of ActiveRecord, and most importantly I removed the "EM.defer" from around my loading function. It seems I do not know how to use EventMachine properly, and it was actually interfering with multithreading. I am looking to switch over to Postgres or MySQL for production to hopefully increase performance.